# Basic Vector Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vector-analysis

This is a basic calculs/pre-calcuus question, that am having trouble with. For real matrices $A_{n \times n}$,$X_{n \times n}$ and $K_{n \times n}$  and a vector $c_{n \times 1}$, I want to have the derivative of the below function w.r.t the vector $c$ in a vector/matrix notation and not in terms of the individual entries of $c$. i.e the derivative w.r.t $c$ and not the derivative w.r.t each entry $c_i$. Note that $x_{i \mathbb{.}}$ denotes the row $i$ of $X$. I'd like to see a few steps in reasonable detail if you are re-arranging the below function in matrix notation! I also would like to have the second derivative w.r.t $c$.

The function is :
$\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}\left[\sum_{q=1}^nc_qK(x_{i\mathbb{.}},x_{q\mathbb{.}})-\sum_{l=1}^nc_lK(x_{j\mathbb{.}},x_{l\mathbb{.}})\right]^2$

Comment: Maybe if you write the expression in matricial form, it will be easier to work with.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sum_{q=1}^n$ and $\sum_{\ell=1}^n$?

Comment: @littleO Yes! That is right.Edited and awaiting an answer.

Comment: @Pragabhava If I could represent this in a matrix form- I would not have posted this question. That is the reason-the differentiation seemed harder, to do in this form and get an answer in vector/matrix form

Comment: For clarification, what does $K(x_i, x_q)$ represent, exactly?

Comment: $K(x_i, x_q)$ can be viewed as the $i$, $q$ entry of a matrix $K$.                                                         $K(x_i, x_q)$ tells us that this scalar entry was formed by a function acting on the rows $x_i$, $x_q$ of $X$

Comment: @qlinck The thing is that, for example, in the term under the square root looks like there is a dot product of vector $c$ with row $i$ of $K$, etc. Why don't you write a small example of what is $K$, $c$ and $A$ (i.e. $n = 2,\,3$).

Comment: @Pragabhava There is no square root. I believe you meant square. K,c and A are fixed matrices/vectors with real-entries. There are infinite examples to what real-numbers they can take. That said, yes-there indeed is an inner product(dot product).

Comment: @qlinck Sure, I meant square. I still don't understand the notation. Can you put a concrete example of $K$, $A$ and $c$, i.e. $K = \begin{pmatrix}\square & \square \\ \square & \square  \end{pmatrix}$?